# Overriding AnimationPlayer functions

Tags: overriding, godot, gdscript

I'm trying to override my animation player functions like this:

```
tool
extends AnimationPlayer

func seek (seconds:float,update:bool=false ) -> void:
    print("seek =>",seconds)
    .seek(seconds,update)

func advance (delta:float) -> void:
    print("advanced=>",delta)
    .advance(delta)

func play (name:String="", custom_blend:float=-1, custom_speed:float=1.0,from_end:bool=false) -> void:
    print("play")
    .play(name,custom_blend,custom_speed,from_end)
```

but I have no idea why it isn't working, nothing is being printed when I test it

I'm particularly interested in `seek()`, when I move the time bar/when the animation is playing, it should be simultaneously print the `seconds` of where it is

[image]

Basically I'm trying to track the time bar

Answer (score 1):

These methods are not virtual.

*Some people "override" non-virtual Godot methods (e.g. `add_child`) but the instances where people report that working, it is because of the type information (or lack thereof). And I should emphasize it is not overriding, but hiding the original method from late binding.*

If the code that is calling `seek` knows it is an `AnimationPlayer`, it will call `seek` from the `AnimationPlayer` class. And since `seek` from the `AnimationPlayer` class is not virtual, your code does not have a chance to run. *If it were doing late binding, then it might, but you should not rely on that working.*

The case we are talking about, is the animation panel in the editor. Which is written in C++ and thus would know it is dealing with an `AnimationPlayer`.

---

### Hacking the animation panel

First of all, make an `EditorPlugin`. *You can refer to the documentation on [Making Plugins](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/plugins/editor/making_plugins.html).* But, to cover the basics:

- Go to Project -> Project Settings… -> Plugins and then click on Create.
- Godot gives you a form to fill information about the Plugin.
- Once you fill the form, it will create an `EditorPlugin` script on the sub folders of the "addons" folder you specified and with the name you specified.

You got your `EditorPlugin` script? Good.

*The first steps are as I described in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70948799/402022).*

You can get the current `AnimationPlayer` like this:

```
tool
extends EditorPlugin


var edited_animation_player:AnimationPlayer


func handles(object:Object) -> bool:
    return object is AnimationPlayer
    

func edit(object:Object) -> void:
    edited_animation_player = object
    print(edited_animation_player)
```

And you can get a reference to the `AnimationToolsPanel` like this:

```
var animation_tools_panel:AnimationToolsPanel


func _enter_tree() -> void:
    var control:= Control.new()
    var animation_player_editor:Control
    add_control_to_bottom_panel(control, "probe")
    for sibling in control.get_parent().get_children():
        if (sibling as Control).get_class() == "AnimationPlayerEditor":
            animation_player_editor = sibling
            break

    remove_control_from_bottom_panel(control)
    if animation_player_editor == null:
        push_error("Unable to find animation player editor")
```

Alright, now that we got that, we can extract some stuff from it. In particular we want:

- The control that holds the name of the current animation.
- The control that holds the current time.

So, let us have variables for those two:

```
var animation_name_input:OptionButton
var animation_time_input:SpinBox
```

Now, the first child of the `AnimationToolsPanel` is the top bar. And the top bar contains the controls we want. So we are going to iterate over the children of the top bar to find them:

```
    var found_option_button:OptionButton
    var found_spin_box:SpinBox
    for child in animation_player_editor.get_child(0).get_children():
        if child is OptionButton:
            found_option_button = child as OptionButton
        elif child is SpinBox:
            found_spin_box = child as SpinBox
        
        if (
            is_instance_valid(found_option_button)
            and is_instance_valid(found_spin_box)
        ):
            break

    animation_name_input = found_option_button
    animation_time_input = found_spin_box
```

Finally, in your `_process` if the references you got (the animation player, the editor panel, and the controls) are valid, you can get the animation name and time:

```
    var index := animation_name_input.selected
    var animation_name = "" if index == -1 else animation_name_input.get_item_text(index)
    var animation_time := animation_time_input.value
```

You want to do that in `_process` so it updates in real time when an animation is playing from the animation panel.

---

Of course, the issue is that you want to subclass `AnimationPlayer`. Thus, in your plugin you can check if the current `AnimationPlayer` is one of yours, and if it isn't disable this mechanism. But if it is, you can tell your custom `AnimationPlayer` what is the current animation and time is according to the panel from the plugin code by calling a custom method that takes those values as parameters, and does whatever you need to do with them.