# How to interact with Tilemap Editor by tool script / editor plugin?

Tags: godot, godot4

Hello Godot's community ! Since Godot 4, the tilemap editor is on bottom pane that can be confused with Tileset editor and harder to use for non-dev users. So I tried to write an Editor Plugin in a Dock where there are only the images of base tiles chosen in a tileset and when I click on them, I want to toggle the bottom panel to the TileMap editor, select the paint tool and the right tile.

The only hints I found in the doc is about [short cuts](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/editor/default_key_mapping.html#tile-map-editor), the paint tool is defined by Editor setting : `tile_map_editor/paint_tile` but can't be set with `get_editor_interface().get_editor_settings().set_setting("tile_map_editor/paint_tile", true)`
and I found nothing about tile selection.

The implementation of the [tilemap editor in Godot source code](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/tree/master/editor/plugins/tiles) appears to be a plugin, but in C++. so I don't know if i can interact with it in godot script.

Comment: I don't have the time to look into this right now, but this might give you an idea: [Overriding AnimationPlayer functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73939875/402022) (except, of course, that is for the animation panel).

Comment: thanks for a good start, I didn't think of the keywords for other elements in the bottom panel. I have lots of questions about your answers but that will be to complete the picture. In the meantime with this, the source code and [godot_editor_debugger_plugin](https://github.com/Zylann/godot_editor_debugger_plugin/tree/godot4) I should be fine and I'll edit the question later. Thanks again!