# How to add animations .tres to Animation Player (gui tool) programmatically?

Tags: animation, tooltip, gdscript, godot3

Is it possible to load animations .tres at same time programmatically to Animation Player (gui tool)? I know animations are resources, I did read some godot docs, I didn't find anything related to 'load to animationPlayer tool (gui)'. I have a lot of animations (.tree file extension) in the FilSystem (res://...) and I would like to load or add them to the Animation Player tool programatically if possible.

Just to clear up, I have attach an iamge of the load button of Animation Player too (gui). I would like to use that load way, but programmatically if possible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

The Animation panel (what you are calling "AnimationPlayer Tool (gui)") is to edit `AnimationPlayer` nodes, and there is no API to manipulate it.

*You might be able to hack your way to it, see [Overriding AnimationPlayer functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73966961/402022). But it won't be useful if the `AnimationPlayer` being edited does not have the animations.*

Thus, what you would do is add `Animation`s to an `AnimationPlayer` which is being edited in the Animation panel.

---

If you are writing an `EditorPlugin`, you would get a call to `_handles` to check if it can handle a `Node`, so you can implement it to tell Godot your `EditorPlugin` handles `AnimationPlayer`s:

```
func _handles(object:Object) -> bool:
    return object is AnimationPlayer
```

And then you will get a call to `_edit`:

```
var edited_animation_player:AnimationPlayer = null

func _edit(object:Object) -> void:
    var animation_player := object as AnimationPlayer
    if is_instance_valid(animation_player):
        edited_animation_player = animation_player
```

That way you can have a reference to the currently edited `AnimationPlayer`, which should be the same in the Animation panel.

---

To add an animation to an `AnimationPlayer`, you need to get an `AnimationLibrary` (either get one from the `AnimationPlayer` or add a new one) and call `add_animation` on it. *The default `AnimationLibrary` has empty name).*

For example:

```
var animation_library = animation_player.get_animation_library("")
animation_library.add_animation(animation_name, animation)
```

Comment: How about to export those animations.tres into a package with pck extension, and then load that package into the AnimationPlayer panel by using the load button? I've tried to export only animations.tres, but some how I can't do it or I'm doing something wrong, so I can't guarantee that it can be possible.